# Do a set number of requests per hour in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

We've use an API that impose a rate-limit per hour.

I wonder what'll be the best way to do a set number of requests per hour to the API for our own scripts. I.e.: Making 10 request per hour to not exceed our allowance and avoids overcharges.

I was thinking just using `sleep(60*6)` in my loop but API calls can take minutes, so it might be doing a lot less requests than allowed.

What will be the best practice to spread out our requests?

**Edit:**

I ended doing something like this, what do you guys think?

```
while(queue.size > 0) do
  Thread.new {
    element = queue.pop
    # do the rate limited API calls and things 
  }
  sleep(60*6)
end
```

Comment: have you checked this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806911/throttling-outbound-api-calls-generated-by-a-rails-app

Comment: Onli was saying about gem https://github.com/ryancalhoun/throttle-queue

Comment: what should happen to requests 11 & 12?  do they get rescheduled or dropped?

Comment: @Anthony got charged extra, so it's not dramatic.

Comment: We need more information to give you a sensible answer. Presumable you have a queue of jobs. 1a. Must the jobs in your queue be dispatched to the API in FIFO (first-in, first-out) order? 1b. If "no" to 1a, does the API service time distribution vary by job and if so do you know the distributions of API service time for each job in queue? 2. Do you know the average time between jobs joining the queue? (cont..)

Comment: 3a. Is there a cost to having jobs delayed?  3b. If "yes" to 3a how is that cost determined, how is the penalty cost for exceeding 10 jobs per hour computed and is the limit 10 jobs per clock hour or 10 jobs in every 60 minute period? (cont.)

Comment: The approach you should take depends on answers to these questions. If, for example, there is no cost to you if the API call is delayed for a job in your queue, you should at all cost avoid going over the 10 jobs per hour limit. On the other hand, if you incur a high cost for jobs being delayed you might happily feed jobs to the API as fast as possible and not worry about penalty costs. Lastly, if you know some jobs take much less time than others that may affect your scheduling (just as supermarkets have "10 or fewer items" lines).

Comment: You can always dump your requests into some kind of work queue and pull them out at a regular interval.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Very interesting. We are actually building also the server API side, but wanted to try it out to see if it's easy to space requests on the client side with couple of actual customers helping them out directly. What do you think is the most common and best practices?

Comment: @CarySwoveland basically our actual issue (on the servers side) is if you submit all you monthly allowance in 5 minutes it will block and/or slow down our service (we depend on external things like CAPTCHAs solvers which scale up very bad) while costing us significant money. Hence our current experimentation with hourly billing.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you with best practices here. I'm just a (pure-) Ruby hobbyist with a background in mathematical modelling.

Answer (score 0):

consider [rack attack](https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack) middleware

to sum it up - you keep somewhere (in memory, in database like `redis`) number of requestes executed by specific client (know by IP, identity or in any other form) within given time.

Comment: Very interesting,  but we've the reverse issue, we want to limit ourself from doing too many requests to an external API.

Comment: read about circuit breaker pattern - I believe it could be used also in your context